# Visual C#, Perform DataGridView cell click dynamically?

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, invoke

I have a `DataGridView` control named `dgvMain1` and a `CellClick` event.

Is it possible to invoke that event dynamically like the `PerformClick()` method in the `Buttons`!?

Comment: This topic might answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841178/how-to-call-an-event-manually-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead I would put your code in a method and then call the method from the CellClick event. This way you don't need to call the event but can call the method instead.